# Twitter share android titanium with social.js file not working

Tags: android, twitter, titanium

I have to share data on twitter for that I have used social.js file it works great on iOS but in android it return access pin only and stuck there.
Can some one tell me to how to solve issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically issue with twitter new API's when I have used

```
var social = require('alloy/social');
```

instead of others social.js files then it solved my issue.